# What could be the cause of the app crash that I have been encountering every time I click an item from the RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am relatively new to the field of Android Application development, and I have been meaning to ask this problem I have been trying to resolve for hours. The issue is that every time I click a card view from the fragment with the RecyclerView, the app crashes showing this error from the "Problem" tab.

[Error from "Problem" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf1uw.png)

What I expect to happen is to print a Toast message showing the corresponding User ID of a card view.
[Clickable Card Views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVZdz.png)

Here is the code of the Fragment with with cards and recycler view:

```
class UserDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var userDetailsViewModel: UserDetailsViewModel
//    private lateinit var binding: FragmentUserDetailsBinding


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val binding: FragmentUserDetailsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_user_details,
            container,
            false
        )


        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application
        val dao = RegisterDatabase.getInstance(application).registerDatabaseDao
        val repository = RegisterRepository(dao)
        val factory = UserDetailsViewModelFactory(repository, application)

        userDetailsViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(UserDetailsViewModel::class.java)

        binding.userDetailsLayout = userDetailsViewModel

        val adapter = MyRecycleViewAdapter(RegisterEntityListener { userId ->
            Toast.makeText(activity, userId.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        })

        binding.usersRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        userDetailsViewModel.users.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            it?.let {
                adapter.submitList(it)
            }
        })

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this


        userDetailsViewModel.navigateTo.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { hasFinished ->
            if (hasFinished == true) {
                val action = UserDetailsFragmentDirections.actionUserDetailsFragmentToLoginFragment()
                NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(action)
                userDetailsViewModel.doneNavigating()
            }
        })

        binding.usersRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this.context)
        return binding.root
    }


}
```

Here is the code of the RecyclerView adapter using ListAdapter

```
class MyRecycleViewAdapter(val clickListener: RegisterEntityListener): ListAdapter<RegisterEntity, MyRecycleViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>(DiffCallBack()) {

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(item!!, clickListener)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        return MyViewHolder.from(parent)
    }
    
    

    class MyViewHolder (val binding: ListItemBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(user: RegisterEntity, clickListener: RegisterEntityListener) {
            binding.clickListener = clickListener
            binding.FirstNameTextView.text = user.firstName
            binding.secondNameTextView.text = user.lastName
            binding.userTextField.text = user.userName
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): MyViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ListItemBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return MyViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }

    }

}


class DiffCallBack: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<RegisterEntity>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: RegisterEntity, newItem: RegisterEntity): Boolean {
        return oldItem.userId == newItem.userId
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: RegisterEntity, newItem: RegisterEntity): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

class RegisterEntityListener(val clickListener: (userId: Int) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(user: RegisterEntity) = clickListener(user.userId)
}
```

Here is the layout of the ViewHolder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.example.login_register.database.RegisterEntity" />
        <variable
            name="clickListener"
            type="com.example.login_register.userDetails.RegisterEntityListener" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:onClick="@{() -> clickListener.onClick(user)}"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/list_item_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linear_layout_2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/First_name_text_View"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/second_name_text_View"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                        android:textSize="30dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/user_TextField"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:textColor="@color/cardview_light_background"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

I tried searching for hours and unfortunately, I was not able to resolve the problem because I cannot find other similar problems or whenever I found something somehow similar, I cannot understand it because they are written in Java. If there are additional information needed (e.g., other source code files of the android project), I am very much obliged to provide them. Any response would be highly appreciated Thank you very much!

I would also like to inform that I am using [this](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-interacting-with-items?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-development-with-kotlin-10%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fkotlin-android-training-interacting-with-items#3) learning material as a reference to achieve what my goal for this android project or exploration.

Comment: did you try to debug? this way its really hard to figure out whats the problem. Also, it says `unknown source` which makes it even harder to identify the error.  Did you try clicking on it? I should take you to some line in some class in your application. Please post the line on which it points(it may not be your application's file)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response regarding my question! Indeed, it was harder to resolve because of "Unknown Source:2". Upon clicking it, I was redirected to "MyRecycleViewAdapter.kt" (the RecycleView adapter) specifically to line 2 which is blank ["Unknown Source:2"](https://imgur.com/a/ttf35Uv).

I also clicked "ListItemBindingImpl:143" which seemed to show a lot of errors (in red markers on scroll bar) ["ListItemBindingImp:143"](https://imgur.com/a/xCRtkH5)

I also clicked "OnClickListener.java:11" which opens this file: ["OnClickListener.java:11"](https://imgur.com/a/2bvGHmd)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be here in the RecyclerView code.

```
class RegisterEntityListener(val clickListener: (userId: Int) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(user: RegisterEntity) = clickListener(user.userId)
}
```

The error states `com.example.login_register.userDetails.RegisterEntityListener.onClick`, which appears to be this onClick function. It says the parameter user is null.

The function appears to be called here. `android:onClick="@{() -> clickListener.onClick(user)}"`. I see user defined earlier in that file, but I think there may be a problem pulling that user from the card that you select. I didn't see anything about how you're assigning a user to each card, but I would look there and see why it might be null when you call that user when it's pressed.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response regarding my question. I'm sorry but I can't seem to find the probable reason as to why onClick on the list_item.xml returns null. I tried reimplementing list_item.xml by simplifying the layout of the ViewHolder by enclosing the TextViews for First Name, Last Name, and Username inside a clickable ConstraintLayout. However, the error or problem still persisted as the error prompt was still the same from the "Run" tab. May I ask where (e.g., project file or class) I could go to investigate why it always returns null when pressed?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem, and I would like to inform you how I fixed it in case someone encountered it in the future. From the adapter **(MyRecycleViewAdapter class from MyRecycleViewAdapter.kt)**, I added `binding.user = user` specifically in the **fun bind() of the inner class UserViewHolder** like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfVQx.png) because in the layout of my ViewHolder (list_item.xml), there are two databindings, one from the RegisterEntity and from the RegisterEntityListener. I have set the "android:onClick" attribute of the CardView to `"@{() -> clickListener.onClick(user)}"` which means it requires the user from the first data binding. Without setting it from the adapter, no user is passed thus, the NullPointerException happens.

I'm not sure if that's the correct explanation but nevertheless, it was fixed. Thank you for those who answered!